# spring variable injection from an autowired object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a class like this -

```
@Service
public class SomeClass {

@Autowired
Environment env;

private String property;

@Value("${pty}")
public void setPty(String pty) {
    pty = environment.getProperty("pty");
   } 
}
```

I'm trying to inject the 'pty' variable from another class 'Environment' which is autowired and I get this exception when my server startups

> Error creating bean with name 'someClass': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire method: public void
>   service.facade.ActionFacade.setPty(java.lang.String);
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not
>   resolve placeholder 'pty' in string value "${pty}"

Comment: Post your spring config.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is because there is no property `pty` in your  Spring context. `@Value` lookup the placeholder 'pty' in the resource files loaded.

In your case it is not required as you need to get it from `Environment` class which you have `Autowired` already, below code will give you the idea.

```
@Service
public class SomeClass {

 @Autowired
 Environment env;
 private String property;

 @PostConstruct
 public void init(){
    property=env.getProperty("pty");
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sridhar! That worked. I'm completely new to Spring and hence this doubt

Answer (score 0):

Try [@PostConstruct](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html)

> The PostConstruct annotation is used on a method that needs to be executed after dependency injection is done to perform any initialization.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    property = env.getProperty("pty");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of Spring bean life cycles:
1. InitializingBean -> afterPropertiesSet 
2. @PostConstruct

```
public class EmployeeService implements InitializingBean{

    private Employee employee;

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
   property = env.getProperty("pty");
}

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

[image]